# Given any ring $A$, how to obtain $A$ from a ring $B$, in which p is invertible?

Tags: ring-theory

On page 27 of [this book](http://sci-lib.org/books_1/F/fesenko.pdf), it is asserted that  any ring can be obtained viâ the operations of subrings, quotient rings, and polynomial rings, from a ring in which $p$ is invertible. And I want to know how one deduces this?

> > Given any ring $A$, how to find a ring $B$, in which $p$ is invertible, such that $A$ can be obtained from $B$ by operations of subrings, quotient rings, and polynomials rings? Here $p$ is a non-zero prime number.

The authors states this in such a way that I wonder if this is quite a common-sense in the subject. But I have never heard of results in this direction. So references are also welcomed.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: I believe the question in the title box isn't correctly put. Don't you mean "how to obtain B from a ring A"?

Comment: In fact the question concerns with finding one $B$ such that $A$ could be obtained in the assigned manner.

Comment: Are you sure $p=0$ is not ruled out by the author? The section starts by talking about "positive characteristic" and starts assuming merely $p=0$ *in* $B$ later in (8.2)

Comment: I deleted that part now. But in my book(not the same as in the link), it is not specified that $p \neq 0$, so my confusion arises. Sorry for that.

Comment: Well, in the book you linked at we're talking about the prime of a local field and stuff, so *clearly* $\,p\neq 0\,$ and I suppose this is a given in any stuff related to this...

Comment: Have you heard about localization and are just looking for alternate descriptions? If not, it is possible that looking up information on localization is all you need. In particular, if $R$ is an integral domain and $p \neq 0$ then the ring you are interested in can be obtained as a subring of the field of fractions $K(R)$ of $R$. If $R$ is not an integral domain then one needs to kill the elements $q$ for which $pq = 0$ since otherwise we'd get $q = p^{-1}pq = 0$. I suppose this killing might also be described using standard operations.

Comment: @Marek I am interested in the localisational approach. Per chance you could write up a more detailed answer? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, it seems the rings here are supposed to be commutative --- see the beginning of (8.1) on page 26 of the book mentioned in the question.  I also assume $p\neq0$.  Suppose we take $B$ to be the polynomial algebra over $\mathbb Q$ in a large set of indeterminates, at least as large as some generating set for the ring $A$.  Because I used $\mathbb Q$ as the coefficients, $p$ is invertible in this $B$.  Let $B'$ be the subring of $B$ consisting of polynomials whose coefficients are integers.  This is the polynomial ring over $\mathbb Z$ in the same set of indeterminates, and it is also the free commutative ring in those indeterminates.  There is a surjection from the set of indeterminates onto a generating subset of $A$ (because we started with enough indeterminates), and this surjection extends (uniquely) to a surjective ring-homomorphism from $B'$ onto $A$.  Thus, $A$ is exhibited as a quotient of a subring $B'$ of a ring $B$ in which $p$ is invertible.

If we don't assume that rings are commutative, the same idea works.  Just take $B$ to be the $\mathbb Q$-algebra generated by a large enough set of non-commuting indeterminates.

Comment: So basically the process goes as follows: $Q[x_i] \to Z[x_i] \to A$. Right?

Comment: Right, as long as the arrows indicate *only* the direction of the process, not some homomorphisms, and as long as $x_i$ is understood to be a big batch of indeterminates.

Comment: Thanks for this interesting answer thus.

Answer (score 0):

Let $p\in A$ be an element which is not a zero divisor. Consider the polynomial $pT-1\in A[T]$ and let $B:=A[T]/(Tp-1)$ be the quotient. Then, $T$ becomes an inverse for $p$ in $B$. I think that on some level, that's what you want.

Comment: Unfortunately, this might kill your ring.  Suppose, for example, that $A$ is $\mathbb Z/4$ and $p=2$. Formally adjoining a reciprocal for 2 will produce the zero ring. In this particular example, you can use $B=\mathbb Q$, in which 2 is invertible. Then $\mathbb Z$ is a subring, and $\mathbb Z/4$ is a quotient of the subring. I assume something like this must be what's wanted in the general case.

Comment: I asked for $p$ not to be a zero divisor.

Comment: Oops; I missed that.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. However it appears that we do need to deal with some more general situations, where $p$ might even be a zero-divisor.